# What do the values in a CVPixelBuffer mean that is returned from a VNGeneratePersonSegmentationRequest?

Tags: ios, coreml, vision, apple-vision, core-video

I use Apple's Vision Framework to create a matte image for a person that is found in a user provided image. I want to analyze the results from a `VNGeneratePersonSegmentationRequest` to understand, for example, if the request has found a person at all and if so, how large the resulting mask is relative to the source image (either the mask's extent or the number of opaque pixels).

The result of a `VNGeneratePersonSegmentationRequest` is a `VNPixelBufferObservation`, and apparently it doesn't support a confidence level (`confidence` is always `1.0`) or a result count like `numberOfFoundPeople`.

What I try instead is to analyze the resulting `CVPixelBuffer` directly. I obtain it like this:

```swift
let personSegmentationRequest = VNGeneratePersonSegmentationRequest()
personSegmentationRequest.outputPixelFormat = kCVPixelFormatType_OneComponent8

let requestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(url: imageUrl)
try requestHandler.perform([personSegmentationRequest])

let mask = personSegmentationRequest.results![0]
let maskBuffer = mask.pixelBuffer
CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(maskBuffer, .readOnly)
defer {
  CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(maskBuffer, .readOnly)
}
```

My idea now is to look at the individual pixel values of the buffer. I assumed that I could get the mask's size with `CVPixelBufferGetWidth` and `CVPixelBufferGetHeight`, and get one byte per pixel whereas a `0` value means "fully transparent" and `255` means "fully opaque".

Apparently, that's not correct: The pixel buffer has always a size of `2016x1512` or `1512x2016`, but `CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow` returns either `2048` or `1536`, so I have some extra bytes per row. How does this add up? `CVPixelBufferGetExtendedPixels` returns `0` for all directions, so there is no padding.

Also, if I look at the first few values in the buffer, they're not what I expect. Here's my code to print the first 10 values of the buffer:

```swift
let baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(maskBuffer)!
let pointer = baseAddress.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self)
print((0...10).map({ String(pointer[$0]) }).joined(separator: ","))
```

Here are example outputs for images that contain either **a person in the center of the image** or **no person at all**:

```swift
1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

4,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

9,4,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0

2,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

The values should correspond to the pixels at a corner of the source image, and I would always expect all zeroes for my example images.

What's strange is that when I ignore these results and simply create a `CIImage` with this `CVPixelBuffer`, rescale it and apply it as a mask using `CoreImage` (as in Apple's example code), the result looks correct, and I do not see semi-transparent pixels in the corners.

What's going on? Do I misunderstand the `CVPixelBufferGet*` methods? Does the data in the pixel buffer contain metadata?

Answer (score 1):

After some more research, I assume that the difference between the number of bytes per row and the pixel buffer's width arises from a required byte alignment in Core Video (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49251219/1821701)).

The small nonzero values are in fact visible when the buffer is applied as an image mask, but the values are small enough that the impact is barely noticeable. I would assume that they are artifacts of the ML model and they can be ignored.